# How to create a waiting page in Django

Tags: ajax, django, jquery

I am constructing an application that need a lengthy calculation. After a user submitted the information, it need about 30 minutes to calculate and then return the result. So I am considering to add a “please wait" page.

I followed instructions mentioned in the following link,
http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/c1b0d916bbf86868
However, when I submit something, it stays in  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/please_wait`
and will not redirect to the result page like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/display_DHM`

does anybody know what is going on?

Here are all related files, I tried various ways, but when I
submit a form, it only return the please_wait page and then stay there
forever. There is no redirect happened.
Since I want to check if it works first, there is no actual
calculation in the code.

#### url.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
       (r'^test$',views.test_form),
       (r'^please_wait', views.please_wait),
   url(r'^run_DHM$', views.run_DHM, name="run_DHM") ,
   url(r'^displayDHM', views.display_DHM, name="displayDHM")
)
```

#### view.py

```
def test_form(request):
       return render_to_response('test.html')

def please_wait(request):
       return render_to_response('please_wait.html')

def run_DHM(request):
      ### lengthy calculations... ...
       return HttpResponse("OK")

def display_DHM(request):
   return render_to_response('display_DHM.html')
```

#### test.html

```
{% extends "baseFrame.html" %}

{% block maincontent %}
 <form method="POST" action="please_wait">
  <p>Test:</p>
  <div id="address"></div>
  <p>Type your value in here:</p>
  <p><textarea name="order" rows="6" cols="50" id="order"></
textarea></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" /></p>
 </form>
{% endblock %}
```

#### please_wait.html

```
<html>Please wait
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/
jquery-1.7.1.min.js">
$.getJSON('{% url run_DHM %}', function(data) {
       if (data == 'OK') {
                 window.location.href = '{% url displayDHM %}';
           } else {
                 alert(data);
           }
   });
</script>
</html>
```

#### display_DHM.html

```
<HTML>
<BODY>END FINALLY!</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You should move this process to background, enqueue it or something like that. Celery is the right way to do this. Also you can use threads.

Answer (score 1):

I write here because I can't use the comment space. My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837217/django-create-a-changing-button-or-waiting-page) is a bit similar to yours and maybe the answer can help you.

Briefly:

the question:

> I have an external python program, named c.py, which "counts" up to 20 seconds. I call it from my Django app views.py and in the html page I have a button to start it. It's ok (= in Eclipse I can see that c.py prints 0,1,2,3,...20 when I press the button on the webpage) but I would like that the button changes from "GO" to "WAIT" during c.py process (or I would like to perform a waiting page during the counting or also a pop-up).

the answer:

> You would need to be able to report back the status of c to the client
>   via ajax long polling or WebSockets, or, if you don't care about the
>   incremental status of c and just want to change the text of the link,
>   you'll need to use JavaScript to set the value when the click event of
>   the link fires:

**views.py**

> ```
> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
> from django.http import JsonResponse
>
> def conta(request):
>     c.prova(0)
>     redirect = reverse('name_of_home_user_view')
>     return JsonResponse({'redirect': redirect})
> ```

and **js**:

> ```
> // assuming jQuery for brevity...
>
> $(document).ready(function() {
>
>     // avoid hard-coding urls...
>     var yourApp = {
>         contaUrl: "{% url 'conta' %}"
>     };
>
>     $('#btnGo').click(function(e) {
>         e.preventDefault();  // prevent the link from navigating
>
>         // set css classes and text of button
>         $(this)
>             .removeClass('btn-primary')
>             .addClass('btn-danger')
>             .text('WAIT');
>
>         $.get(yourApp.contaUrl, function(json) {
>              window.top = json.redirect;
>         });
>     });
> });
> ```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @Maxime Rouiller: I have not sufficient reputation to comment so I posted an answer with my question not with the aim to obtain more answers but because I think that its answer can be useful for this question. I did not right?

Comment: After review, yeah. It's kind of a failure of the system. But after viewing the extensive answer that you gave, it would not have fit in a comment anyway. I recommend you add a few nice answers like this and earn the 50 reputation needed to comment. Added an upvote to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need lengthy calculations I think you could be interested in [celery](http://celeryproject.org). Nice waiting pages (progress indicators?) would be a byproduct.

Comment: Can anybody give some example on how to do it? I know nothing about ajax, celery....